# How to copy and paste cells in VBA

Tags: vba

I am having troubles copy and pasting using VBA. I need it to behave just like it does when I use the copy/paste functions on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this...

```
Range("D14", Cells(Rows.Count, "E")).Copy ' Copy the range
Range("AH14", Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste it elsewhere
```

This will allow you to copy multiple cells and paste them anywhere,. Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped :)